# How to print the tokens like with "-tokens" in the terminal?

Tags: java, antlr4

In the terminal (or console), I can just do `grun Exp eval -tokens`, but how do I do that from Java? I found that, that do like `-tree`:

```java
ParseTree tree = parser.eval();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

But I can't find anything similar for `-tokens`.

**Edit 1**: I found something with `lexer.reset()`:

```java
lexer.reset();
for (Token token: lexer.getAllTokens()) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

But the token are only numbers like `<4>`, I would like to get the real name from it.

**Edit 2**: I got it:

```java
Vocabulary vocabulary = lexer.getVocabulary();
lexer.reset();
for (Token token: lexer.getAllTokens()) {
    System.out.println(token.getLine() + ":" + token.getCharPositionInLine() + " '" + token.getText() + "' " + vocabulary.getSymbolicName(token.getType()));
}
```

This isn't the exact same thing but the main infos still!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```java
Vocabulary vocabulary = lexer.getVocabulary();
lexer.reset();
for (Token token: lexer.getAllTokens()) {
    System.out.println(token.getLine() + ":" + token.getCharPositionInLine() + " '" + token.getText() + "' " + vocabulary.getSymbolicName(token.getType()));
}
```